# How to Make a Java Program Sleep with JavaFX 8?

Tags: multithreading, javafx, sleep

I am still getting used to JavaFX and I am having some troubles making a dialog window. Basically, I want to have a splash screen that opens when the user opens the program, the window will contain some setup fields and an OK button.

In Java 7, with Swing, I would set up the window and then have a method that displays the splash screen and returns the choices that the user made. To make the method wait for the user to hit OK before returning, I would use the following loop:

```
while (!finished) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // catch exception
    }
}
```

The finished variable would be a boolean that was marked as true when the user clicked OK.

Now, as I try to recreate this in JavaFX, I am running into a major problem. When I call the sleep method, the JavaFX doesn't seem to like that and the program crashes. The window displays but with just an empty white background and none of the components that were setup.

Comment: Thank you for redirecting me to this. I searched forever and never came across that post. This works perfectly for what I need!